# When playing Saints Row 3 in co-op, does my progress carry over to my single player save?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I want to play with a friend in Saints Row 3, but he's at a different part of the plot missions than I am.  If I save my game while playing in his lobby, do I get credit for having finished the missions we co-op'ed, even though I haven't gotten as far as he has?  If I go back and play alone, can I start the story missions over where I was?

What about side missions and other progress?  How is that tracked if I play the same save in both co-op and single player?

Comment: do you know where the savegame is saved?

Comment: @Robert, I don't, I'm playing on the Xbox 360.  If you want to know the answer, maybe you should ask it as a question?

Comment: I have a worse problem, I get even get onto the coop, I have entere my code fron the spec edition and got my gun, car, clothing etc, but it won't let me onto the coop!?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did some research and asked the guys I co-op with.  I determined the following:

- The person hosting the game's progress determines which story mission comes next.  If you finish a story mission in co-op that is ahead of your own story process, when you catch up (in single player or if you're the host next time) you'll have the option to skip this mission.  If the mission unlocks something (ie, a new crib) you'll have access to this in your game, regardless of whether or not you've gotten there yourself.
- Activities and other side missions count for both people if finished in co-op.
- Challenges in the Saintsbook and controlling parts of the city are determined separately, co-op or not.  For example, if you want the bonus for owning a store, you have to buy that store.
- Assassinations count for both people, if you both have **any** target selected.  It doesn't seem to matter if you've got the same one selected, so long as you both have one marked.  I got credit for 2 or 3 that my buddy was working on halfway across the map, simply because I was working on a different target.
- Vehicle deliveries can only be active on one person at a time.  If you both try to select a vehicle to steal that your partner already has marked, the game will tell you that it's already in progress.
- Collectibles (ie, cash/drugs/photo ops/etc) are tracked separately.
- Disrupting gang operations and completing "survival" challenges counts for both people, if both people were inside of the radius of the operation/challenge when it finished.

You have separate garages, and a vehicle that came from your partner's garage can't be stored in your garage.  (ie, if you steal a tank and put it in your garage, you can't then get the tank out and let him drive it to his garage to get a copy)

I finished the story missions in a co-op game, and I don't have the option to replay the final mission over again.  I don't know if this is a local glitch or a problem with finishing the story in co-op, but I thought I'd add that as a note.

Comment: Does it work the other way around? As in, you're ahead in single player and you can skip stuff in co-op?

Comment: No, whoever is hosting essentially "picks" the story mission you start on, and if your partner is hosting AND lagging behind story-wise, you'll still have to play the mission with him/her.  The skipping only works if you've finished it out-of-order in co-op and then you encounter it in single player.

Comment: Basically the guest player is joining the host player's world, and all choices and consequences fall to the host player. The guest is along for the ride.

Answer (score 1):

When my friend was behind, we could skip missions in co-op.

Also, we could both select the same vehicle target. We were both in the same car and it counted for both of us (passenger got half as much cash some reason).